# Layout.xml file is not visible in the android studio 3.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Am not able to see the layout.xml file in my studio shown below,

[image: please look into the screenshot below]

Can I please know, how this layout file will be enabled to work further!

Thanks all.

Comment: `Project not ready` - Wait for your project to fully sync and index first.

Comment: Can you explain in brief once about your comment @MichaelDodd.

Comment: The IDE is in the middle of doing some work, ensuring your project is properly set up, indexing the files in your project so it can search through those files more efficiently, and so on. You cannot create new files while this work is taking place. If this is taking a very long time, you may need to invalidate your caches and restart Android Studio (`File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart`)

Comment: I have done so many times, this option: Invalidate caches/Restart. @MichaelDodd

Comment: why did you add flutter layout tag in the post????

Comment: because flutter doesn't contains xml files

Comment: sorry, it by mistake!!

Comment: @SaiSushmitha if you want to add some xnl files into an Flutter project - you doing something wrong

Comment: Can I please know what wrong am doing along!! @Eugene

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs many times because of project is not synced properly or gradle is not synced or both project and gradle not synced or maybe you are opening your project after few days

the solution is

- Build -> Clean Project
- Build -> Rebuild Project
- File -> Sync  Project

i have added the screen shots

[image]

[image]

Invalid cache

[image]

Shortcuts for Sync 
if you are using windows `ctrl+alt+y`
for MAC `command+option+y`

Comment: In build option, didnot find the clean project option. And in the tools option too, cannot see the Android  @akshay patil.

Comment: Thanks for screenshots.  In Build option I have only, two options: Generate deploy module to App engine and Analyze Apk. For File option, I don't see Sync project with gradle files in my Android studio.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: 3.3.2 version, am using.

Comment: have you tried shortcut i have edit the post look let me know if you need more help

Comment: please click on invalidate caches/restart option below sync with project files option this will guaranteed help

Comment: Yeah, I tried that option too, but also no changes.

Comment: can you tell me in file -> setting -> build -> gradle does the offline mode checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: It is not checked!!

Comment: then it's ok if that checked then you have to unchecked and again sync the project but don't seemed what problem is?